# Calling Virtual Function of Parent

Tags: c++, linux, inheritance, pointers, casting

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <string>
class Parent{
public:
    Parent(){
    }
    virtual std::string GetString()
    {
        int amount = 1;
        input_event ev[amount];
        ev[0].code = BTN_9;
        ev[0].value = 1;
        char* temp = reinterprt_cast<char*>(ev);
        std::string msg(temp, sizeof(ev) * amount);
        return msg;
    }
};
class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child(){
    }
    virtual std::string GetString()
    {
        int amount = 1;
        input_event ev[amount];
        ev[0].code = BTN_9;
        ev[0].value = 1;
        char* temp = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ev);
        std::string msg(temp, sizeof(ev) * amount);
        return msg;
    }

};

class Child2 : public Parent
{
public:
    Child2(){
    }
    virtual std::string GetString()
    {
        std::string temp(Parent::GetString());
        return temp;
    }

};

TEST(CastToString, test)
{
    Parent parent = Parent();
    Child child1 = Child();
    Child2 child2 = Child2();
    std::string pString(parent.GetString());
    std::string c1String(child1.GetString());
    std::string c2String(child2.GetString());
    EXPECT_EQ(pString, c1String);
    EXPECT_EQ(pString, c2String);
}
```

I just copied in the whole sample.
The problem lies at the call of Child2s GetString function.
It always returns different values hence i assume, there is some allocation problem, but i cant figure it out.

Comment: What is `ev` definition?

Comment: When possible, try to use the copy and paste functionality of your editor and browser. Your code in its current form won't compile.

Comment: @john The code uses `reinterprt_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @hvd Hah! Good spot. Amazes me that someone wouldn't use copy and paste.

Comment: Please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is here

```
  std::string msg(temp, sizeof(ev) * amount);
```

should be

```
  std::string msg(temp, sizeof(ev[0]) * amount);
```

(both places).

Because the array size was wrong you were getting extra garbage bytes in your string, so they didn't compare equal.

Comment: Well I suggest you change the content of your two functions to something sane, like `std::string msg("testing"); return msg;`. This will help you narrow down the problem. Or you could just use a debugger.

Comment: The problem with the sanity is, that i narrowed down the problem to this extend. Somehow the casting is the cause of it. Debugger shows me 2 different strings, in the functions, really dont know what to do with it, thought it is a essential problem.

Comment: @MichaelLatz Are there fields in input_event struct that you have not initialized? Maybe you could try a memset on the array before you assign the values.

Comment: 100 Thanks, that solved the issue, but why is this necessary?

Comment: @MichaelLatz because any uninitialized fields (or even any padding bytes between fields) will have garbage values. Normally this wouldn't matter but because your program makes a string out of the whole array, every last byte gets incorporated into your string, even the garbage bytes.